# WP AppleNews - Use ACF for Author

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The site manages the WP Authors with an Advanced Custom Field.

When an article is published in Apple News, it pulls the native WP author instead of this custom value.

I'm using alleyinteractive/apple-news plugging for the Apple News integration

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter that implements `apple_news_exporter_byline`

This one supports an array of authors taken from ACF:

```
add_filter('apple_news_exporter_byline', 'custom_author', 10, 2);

function custom_author($byline, $post_id) {
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  $post_date = date( 'M j, Y | h:m A', strtotime( $post->post_date ) );
  $author_list = "";

  $author = $post_id ? get_field('acf_author', $post_id) : get_field('acf_author');
  if ($author):
    foreach ($author as $author):
      $name = trim( get_field('person_name', $author->ID) );
      $surname = trim( get_field('person_surname', $author->ID) );
      if (!empty($name) || !empty($surname)) {
          $fullname = "$name $surname";
      } else {
          $fullname = $author->post_title;
      }

      if (!empty($author_list)) {
        $author_list = $author_list.", ".$fullname;
      } else {
        $author_list = $fullname;
      }
    endforeach;
  endif;

  $byline = !empty($author_list) ? sprintf('by %1$s | %2$s', $author_list, $post_date ) : sprintf('by %1$s | %2$s', "MySite", $post_date );

  return $byline;
}
```

More info:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/filter-hook-for-authors/